# Decreasing the space between text and underline in hyperlink

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyperlink, underline

I am playing around with custom hyperlinks for my WordPress page and would like to style them so that the underline hugs the bottom of the text very closely, i.e.: I want to be able to decrease the space between the text and the underline. So far I've found [one solution](https://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines/) that involves using an image in place of the underline, but I wonder if there are other solutions available.

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820185/7126863

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border property of a span and then line-height to create the effect you're looking for without using an image:

```
<a href="link.html"><span>Link</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    line-height: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/Lujyowxz/2/

Comment: Is there a way to do this so it happens automatically with every hyperlink? Not just the ones with the <span> tag?